# dababase driven blackberry app

Tags: database, mobile, blackberry

Can someone please point me to a basic tutorial where I can learn how to display content on a backberry app using a local database that is a part of application package. Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at the Sqlite Demo in Eclipse plugin provided by Blackberry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this [official BB site section](https://developer.blackberry.com/java/documentation/sqlite_intro_1981752_11.html)

Take a look at the left rubricator, there are described steps to work with SQLite.

[And there's a sample app that works with SQLite](https://developer.blackberry.com/java/documentation/data_sqlite_1988900_11.html)